# PyHook download error

Tags: anaconda, spyder, python-wheel, pyhook

I keep getting the following error

pyHook-1.5.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I have downloaded the pyHook onto my computer. But I am unable to solve this error  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyhook

I am using Spyder program from Anaconda, and python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Your Python is almost certainly 32-bit and you're trying to install a 64-bit wheel. Download 32-bit wheel or use 64-bit Python.